# WPF Printing window in pdf format

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a button on my window, when it's clicked, print dialog is being showned.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

        Window currentMainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;

        if ((bool)dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow = currentMainWindow; // do it early enough if the 'if' is entered
            dlg.PrintVisual(this, "Certificate");
        }
    }
```

Now when printing as pdf that window, I get a result as this.

[image]

and in pdf this, the window is cropped in pdf document, but I need the whole window to be printed. What solutions can be here ? Thanks
[image]

EDIT

it is working, only when I choose send to one note in printing options

Comment: what is your window width?

Comment: it is full screen, but does that matter ?

Comment: yes can you please share your UI

Comment: Height="600" Width="800" here are they and I have already posted the UI of window which I want to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it could be printed fully in landscape:

```
dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it is big, and is not fitting in a window :/

Comment: how to change paper height and width, but I saw that they are read-only

Comment: It is not changing, the same with landscape @EkoostikMartin

Comment: in adobe reader no difference, but in  on note the result is as expected

Comment: Can someone please help me in find "print as pdf" option in the dialog window. When my code hits dlg.showdialog().GetvalueorDefault()" i am seeing only "one note" as option kindly help.